# Request permission for microphone on Android M

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to utilize the microphone with Android M. I've tried setting up a permission group in the manifest, and can't get it working properly. Here's what I've got in the manifest:

```
<permission-group android:name="android.permission-group.MICROPHONE"
    android:label="label"
    android:icon="@mipmap/day_icon"
    android:priority="360"/>

<permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MICROPHONE"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
    android:label="label" />
```

I've also tried getting the access through code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission_group.MICROPHONE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{Manifest.permission_group.MICROPHONE},
                REQUEST_MICROPHONE);

    }
```

The alert doesn't show to grant access.

I still don't have access to microphone. Anyone know how get permission for the microphone?

**Note**: This is only not working for Android M

Comment: it's `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`.

Comment: are you trying to create your own permission?

Comment: @DeeV I've already got RECORD_AUDIO in there

Comment: @tyczj mainly I'm just trying to enable the microphone.

Comment: Also the `<permission>` and `<permission-group>` tags are meant for creating permissions.  What you would want is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

Comment: as @DeeV said what you are doing is creating your own permission, all you have to do is list the permission with `uses-permission`

Comment: I've already got this line in my Manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: It's only for API level 23 that this is failing

Comment: you cannot request a group permission either, do you have that in a try catch or something because it should be crashing

Comment: It's not crashing - I can get my microphone-required code to work if I manually enable the microphone in settings

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To request microphone, you should be requesting `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` instead of the permission group `Manifest.permission_group.MICROPHONE`.

So, remove the tags `<permission/>` and `<permission-group/>` in the Manifest because they are to indicate that your want to *create* new permissions rather than *use* them.

Then to request the permission just do this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            REQUEST_MICROPHONE);

}
```

Comment: Why is **RECORD_AUDIO** permission preferable over **MICROPHONE** group?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: You can't request entire groups for some reason, so you really don't have a choice.

Comment: @BhavyaArora REQUEST_MICROPHONE is a request code you provide.  You get the result in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: The link to the relevant page in the docs: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java