# How to check if user revoked microphone permission many times?

Tags: java, android

On Android, if you revoke permission 2 times (I guess), the app cannot ever ask you again.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36270554/10116440 tells to do this to check for permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            REQUEST_MICROPHONE);

}
```

I can only compare to `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` and `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`. How do I know that, if I call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`, it will show the microphone permission popup?

I'd like to show a button for the user to go to the permission on the settings in case there's no more possibility to show the popup.

Comment: You need to read more about it,  check the official documentation [Request app permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), furthermore, you can check [this medium article](https://link.medium.com/erheWZjG5eb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library for permissions .
Example code :

```html
Dexter.withContext(this)
    .withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
        @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {/* ... */}
        @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {/* ... */}
        @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
    }).check();
```

https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter